# What are the weather conditions in Macedonia in May?

Tags: weather-and-climate, hiking, macedonia

We are going to hike in Macedonia in the middle of May. Our plans include hikes in Šipkovica (Tetovo), Mavrovo, Lake Matka, Galichica, Pelister. We are amateurs and we will go for easy-moderate hikes. For what kind of weather should we prepare? How cold is up there?

As far as I understand, April and May are rain periods in Macedonia. How much rain should we expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daytime temperatures are around 10-20°C which seems good for hiking (up to 23°C in Tetovo). Nighttime temperatures can drop down to 0-5°C.

You could get some rain and thunderstorms during a day but also few sunny days in a row...

If you go hiking for a week in April/May, you are pretty likely to get 1 to 3 days with some rain.

Temperatures source : [Accuweather](http://www.accuweather.com)